Commutative Diagram Problem for Exact Sequences of a Length-2 Module
Let $A$ be a finite-dimensional algebra over a field $k$.
Let $M$ be an indecomposable module of length $2$ over $A$ such that $\operatorname{soc}(M) \ncong \operatorname{top}(M)$. Here, $\operatorname{soc}$ and $\operatorname{top}$ refer to the socle and top of a module, respectively (see Socle of a module and Top of a module).
Suppose we have the following two exact sequences:
$$0\to \operatorname{soc} (M) \overset{f}{\longrightarrow} M \overset{g}{\longrightarrow} \operatorname{top}(M) \to 0,$$
$$0\to \operatorname{soc} (M) \overset{u}{\longrightarrow} M \overset{v}{\longrightarrow} \operatorname{top}(M) \to 0,$$
Can we obtain the following commutative diagram:
\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
0 & \longrightarrow & \operatorname{soc}(M) & \overset{f}{\longrightarrow} & M & \overset{g}{\longrightarrow} & \operatorname{top}(M) & \longrightarrow & 0 \\
  &                 & \parallel              &                             & \downarrow{h}                  &                       & \parallel          &                 &   \\
0 & \longrightarrow & \operatorname{soc}(M) & \overset{u}{\longrightarrow} & M & \overset{v}{\longrightarrow} & \operatorname{top}(M) & \longrightarrow & 0,  
\end{array}
i.e., can we find a morphism $h: M \to M$ such that the above diagram commutes? Or is there a counterexample?

Suppose there are nonisomorphic simple modules $U$ and $V$, and a nonsplit short exact sequence
$$0\to U\xrightarrow{f}M\xrightarrow{g}V\to0$$
Suppose also that $k$ has more than two elements, and take $\lambda\in k\setminus\{0,1\}$. Then there is no map $h$ making the diagram
$$
\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
0 & \longrightarrow & U & \overset{f}{\longrightarrow} & M & \overset{g}{\longrightarrow} & V & \longrightarrow & 0 \\
  &                 & \parallel              &                             & \downarrow{h}                  &                       & \parallel          &                 &   \\
0 & \longrightarrow & U & \overset{\lambda f}{\longrightarrow} & M & \overset{g}{\longrightarrow} & V & \longrightarrow & 0,  
\end{array}
$$
commute, since $h$ must be multiplication by $\lambda$ to make the left hand square commute, but must be the identity map to make the right hand square commute.
